# is there a way to install six if I do not have access to internet?

Tags: python, matplotlib, six

I am trying to install matplotlib on my lab computer that does not have internet access. Since it requires six for its full implementation, I am unable to run the scripts that has matplotlib module.
I know how to install six by using pip but am stuck when there is no internet access.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @henist is there any possibility that I can make backup of six? I mean the exe file for six.

Comment: @AshimPaudel there isn't an *"exe file"*, but you can just get the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src) or zip file, as explained below.

Comment: @SimeonVisser answer is good

Comment: Download the zipped repository and then use the setup script.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package by running `pip install six-1.9.0.tar.gz` which requires you to copy `six-1.9.0.tar.gz` to the machine somehow.

Comment: I do not have access to internet! So can i run pip install six-1.9.0.tar.gz without having net access?Can you please elaborate it??

Comment: You download it from another computer and bring it on with a USB.

Comment: How do you expect to download anything without an internet connection? Your logic makes no sense regarding networking and principles of the internet.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: There's nothing odd or strange or "makes no sense" about wanting to use a computer that is not on the internet. Not every installation target is just hobbyist home PC.